# Spotify API add track to online playlist

Tags: php, api, post, curl, spotify

I am making a simple method to add songs to a groupplaylist on spotify.
I'm trying to execute the curl command spotify gives me but i can't get it to work.

```
$url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/*username*/playlists/*playlist*/tracks?uris=*trackId*" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer *Token*';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
           'Bearer' => '*TOKEN*'
        )
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Does anyone know how to get it to work. The only error message i get is 'boolean false'.

**UPDATE:** found some more information about my errors.

```
if(!curl_exec($ch)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}
```

Error: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" - Code: 60

Error 60:
CURLE_SSL_CACERT (60)
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.

I think i am passing the token incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be:

```
$url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/*username*/playlists/*playlist*';
```

Then add this to handle the `-H` parameters:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer *Token*"));
```

Not sure whether you need this or not, may be you can remove this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`